# InDesign Startup Script

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I made a simple startup script for InDesign using javascript with afterOpen that would show an alert when any Indesign document is opened just for testing. I have deleted the script from my scripts folder, but it still runs and alerts pop up for any InDesign file I open. Why? How? Should I uninstall and reinstall InDesign? Is it in a hidden file somewhere?

Comment: First of all - fully restart InDesign. Secondly - check if the copy of the script is in the InDesign Scripts/Startup folder and delete it from there

Answer (score 1):

Because of startup scripts are persistent (in ID "database"). You need to make another script or answer to beforeClose -- Document (beforeQuit -- Application) events, where you need to remove all EventListeners and MenuActions.